# Typeorm is not generating entities on build when using NX

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, monorepo

I'm using nx for a project and Have a NestJS API with Typeorm but when running nx serve app the entities files are not being generated so I get this error when trying to insert data to the database.

```
No metadata for \"Agent\" was found.",
```

when I manually point the .ts entities files to the Entities:[] config so I get this error.

import { Field, ObjectType } from '@nestjs/graphql';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: Are you using `autoLoadEntities: true` in the `TypeormModule.forRoot/Async()` configuration?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel yes I'm using it.    `  { name: 'development',
      type: 'postgres',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 5432,
      username: 'postgres',
      password: '12340',
      database: 'test',
      synchronize: true,
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      logging: true,   entities: [regex to match *.entity.ts]  } `

Comment: Okay, if you have `autoLoadEntities` you don't need the `entities` glob, Nest will pass the entity classes for you based on any entities added to `TypeormModule.forFeature()`

Comment: @JayMcDoniel exactly I was addidng the `entities` glob to test mapping them directly but with `autoLoadEntities` is enough. what happens is that in the `/dist/ * /app ` directory the entities are not being generated after running `nx serve app` so whenever I try to test one addition to the db it says ` No metadata for x was found`

Comment: Is that entity that is being reported in at least one `TypeormModule.forFeature()` import that is being used in your application?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel yes, it's an odd issue to be honest and typeorm does not give me enough details

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? Sami issue here.

Comment: @ItamarSmirra Honestly i don't remember but I think i did solve it. sorry